# Does it matter if I use one kettle bell v.s two ?

Tags: kettlebell

As I move up to heavier kettle-bells for my swing, I've been sticking to using two kettle bells instead of one. So I'll do a 2 hand swing with 25lbs on either hand instead of a 50lbs swing. Does it make a difference ?

Comment: That seems like it would change the mechanics of the movement significantly, I can't picture how I could widen my stance enough to swing two without them hitting the ground at the bottom!  RKC swing or "cross-fit style" swing?

Answer (score 2):

It would change the movement completely. like using dumbbell vs barbell.

One handed would bring in more little stabilizing muscles and it would allow more development of your weaker side. While 2H would be better to develop base strength as you have more control.

Comment: Would you suggest one over the other ?